# Grep only exact string

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I'm using a df command to show disk space but want to grep each line separately:

```
Filesystem     Size   Used  Avail Capacity  Mounted on
/dev/disk2     59Gi   22Gi   37Gi    38%    /
/dev/disk3s2   11Ti  5.2Ti  5.7Ti    48%    /Volumes/UserStorage
/dev/disk4s2   11Ti  5.9Ti  5.0Ti    54%    /Volumes/UserStorage-BACKUP
```

I need to extract the values from /Volumes/UserStorage separate from /Volumes/UserStorage-BACKUP

But the following still gives me both:

```
% df -Pklh | grep /Volumes/UserStorage
/dev/disk3s2   11Ti  5.2Ti  5.7Ti    48%    /Volumes/UserStorage
/dev/disk4s2   11Ti  5.9Ti  5.0Ti    54%    /Volumes/UserStorage-BACKUP
```

Ideas how to get each line separately, I.e.

```
/dev/disk3s2   11Ti  5.2Ti  5.7Ti    48%    /Volumes/UserStorage
```

then

```
/dev/disk4s2   11Ti  5.9Ti  5.0Ti    54%    /Volumes/UserStorage-BACKUP
```

??

Comment: can't you just specify 1 dir as a time to df, ie.  `df -h /Volumes/UserStorage` ? Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use end of the line anchor `$`

```
df -Pklh | grep '/Volumes/UserStorage$'
```

This would match the line which has exactly `/Volumes/UserStorage` string present at the end.

Comment: Thanks Avinash, I did not know about the end of line anchor! I'll mark the question as answered as soon as the time limit arrives! Cheers!

Comment: How to then include a variable name together with the line anchor $? For example `grep '$VOLUMENAME$'` ?

Comment: try `grep "$VOLUMENAME$"` or `grep "$VOLUMENAME"'$'`

Comment: Thanks, the double quotes worked. I had single quotes previously. Cheers!